# Replace usage of production classes in compiled code with simulated classes

Tags: c#, dll-injection

So I have production code, compiled against production dlls. They access the real architecture of the system.

I'm working on a simulator that will simulate this architecture. All the classes in the simulation are named the same and belong to the same namespaces as the production classes.

People can use my simulation dlls to do a rough draft test of their code.

However, if they call existing production business logic that was compiled against the production classes, it will load the existing production dlls and use the real architecture.

If people want to use my simulation, but call existing business logic, I'd have to use some kind of injection to overwrite the dll that loads the production classes.

Is this possible?

For an example:

I have a dll called `Production.dll`
In it there is a class like so.

```
namespace Production
{
    public class A { public void Do(); }
}
```

Now, I have a dll called `Simulation.dll` with the same class and code.

Someone wrote a program called `DoA.exe`

```
public static class Program
{
    public static Main()
    {
        var a = new Production.A();
        a.Do();
    }
}
```

I want to make DoA.exe load my simulation dll, but I may not be able to remove Production.dll from its search path. How can I force it to use Simulation.dll instead.

Comment: Yes, you can do dynamic inspection of DLL's, or even design your code to use a Dependency Injection approach, but it's a complicated problem and is hard to advise without knowing much more about whta the application looks like.

Comment: Indeed you can do that (you'd need to make "simulation" assembly to have the same name/strong name to be able to replace classes without code changes/recompile). But really consider some DI configuration that will allow you to properly reconfigure your programs to use "simulated" implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand better your problem. While I think my original solution is cleaner, this is how to do it "dirty".

Assuming your class schema is like this (simplified):

```
// assembly: Production.dll (no dependencies)
namespace Production {
  public class Test {
    public void Do() {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("Production");
    }
  }
}

// assembly: Simulation.dll (no dependencies)
namespace Production {
  public class Test {
    public void Do() {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("Simulation");
    }
  }
}

// assembly: Usage.dll (dependency on Production.dll)
namespace Usage {
  public class TestUsage {
    public void Do() {
      new Production.Test().Do();
    }
  }
}
```

And finally code that will perform the override:

```
// Console application ConsoleApplication.exe
// dependency on Production.dll, Usage.dll and Simulation.dll
namespace ConsoleApplication {
  internal class AssemblyResolver : MarshalByRefObject {
    static internal void Register(AppDomain domain) {
      var resolver = domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
            typeof(AssemblyResolver).FullName) as AssemblyResolver;

      resolver.RegisterDomain(domain);
    }

    private void RegisterDomain(AppDomain domain) {
      domain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;
    }

    private Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
      var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
      string name = assemblyName.Name;
      // comment out line below and you'll load "Production" instead
      if (name == "Production") {
        name = "Simulation";
      }
      var fileNames = new[] { name + ".dll", name + ".exe" };
      foreach (string fileName in fileNames) {
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(path)) {
          return Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        }
      }

      return null;
    }
  }

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Doable", null, new AppDomainSetup {
        DisallowApplicationBaseProbing = true
      });
      AssemblyResolver.Register(domain);
      domain.DoCallBack(() => {
        // writes out "Simulation"
        new Usage.TestUsage().Do();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I can overload the assembly resolver in the main application, and it will control what "Usage" loads?
That's exactly what I need.

Would there be a way to control what a separate process loads, in case Usage.exe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dependency Injection to handle problems like this:

Suppose you have interface like

```
public interface IDoable {
  void Do();
}
```

in Interfaces.dll
and than you have Production.dll with class like:

```
namespace Production {
  internal class Doable : IDoable {
    public void Do() { Console.Out.WriteLine("Production"); }
  }

  public static class Bootstrapper {
    static void Init(IServiceLocator locator) {
      locator.AddSingleton<IDoable, Doable>();
    }
  }
}
```

and then you have Simulation.dll with class like

```
namespace Simulation {
  internal class Doable : IDoable {
    public void Do() { Console.Out.WriteLine("Simulation"); }
  }

  public static class Bootstrapper {
    static void Init(IServiceLocator locator) {
      locator.AddSingleton<IDoable, Doable>();
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your MainAssembly you can reference both, and resolve what implementation you want to use via configuration (naive example below). Except for the configuration line, you don't really have to care from which assembly the `IDoable` came from - you just use it.

```
public static Main()
{
    Production.Bootstrapper.Init(ServiceLocator.Instance);
    // or you can use
    // Simulation.Bootstrapper.Init(ServiceLocator.Instance);
    IDoable doable = ServiceLocator.Instance.Resolve<IDoable>();
    doable.Do();
}
```

Utility classes (using Microsoft Unity Container from [Enterprise Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789)):

```
public interface IServiceLocator {
  void Add<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom;
  void BuildUp<T>(T instance);
  void BuildUp(Type type, object instance);
  void AddSingleton<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom;
  void AddSingleton<TFrom, TTo>(string name) where TTo : TFrom;
  void AddSingleton(Type from, Type to, string name);
  void AddInstance<T>(T instance);
  T Resolve<T>();
  T Resolve<T>(string name);
}

public class ServiceLocator : IServiceLocator {
  private IUnityContainer m_Container = new UnityContainer();

  public void Add<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom {
    m_Container.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>();
  }

  public void BuildUp<T>(T instance) {
    m_Container.BuildUp<T>(instance);
  }

  public void BuildUp(Type type, object instance) {
    m_Container.BuildUp(type, instance);
  }

  public void AddSingleton<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom {
    m_Container.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
  }

  public void AddSingleton<TFrom, TTo>(string name) where TTo : TFrom {
    m_Container.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(name, new   ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
  }

  public void AddSingleton(Type from, Type to, string name) {
    m_Container.RegisterType(from, to, name, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
  }

  public void AddInstance<T>(T instance) {
    m_Container.RegisterInstance<T>(instance);
  }

  public T Resolve<T>() {
    return m_Container.Resolve<T>();
  }

  public T Resolve<T>(string name) {
    return m_Container.Resolve<T>(name);
  }

  private static IServiceLocator s_Instance;

  public static IServiceLocator Instance {
    get { return s_Instance; }
  }

  static ServiceLocator() {
    var instance = new ServiceLocator();
    instance.AddInstance<IServiceLocator>(instance);
    s_Instance = instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the app that I'm executing.
So I can't add this overhead to it. 
That's my problem.
I could easily do this if I were to recompile everything.

I'm calling App.dll that loads the Production.dll.
I have no control over what that dll does.

I want the App.dll to use Simulation.dll instead.

Comment: Fortunately for everyone who uses C#, a random DLL can't force you to use its classes with no action on the client's part.